# Why garbage is displayed in the thread function? | Pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads

Sorry for my English.
I'm use QT Creator.
I'm just starting to study threads) And this is my first serious problem.
I do not understand why I cannot get the exact value of my string from a thread function.

[With string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOQOV.jpg)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g9lO.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B02pZ.jpg)

I tried many options, but everything turned out to be in vain.
I tried to do 'char *' instead of 'string'
... tried to make structure, but still not working.

[with struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jss7q.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#define NUM_THREAD 4

using namespace std;

struct message_info {
    char* message;
};

void *PrintMessage(void *arg) {
    message_info *new_info;
    new_info = (struct message_info*)arg;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    cout << "ID thread :" << id << new_info->message << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t id_stream[NUM_THREAD];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++){
        struct message_info call_mess;
        call_mess.message = "This is messaf";
        int rec = pthread_create(id_stream, NULL, PrintMessage, (void *)&call_mess);
        if (rec != 0) {
            cout << "Error: Thread not created | " << rec << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code into the question. Following links to external resources is something most people don't want to do. Also as code is just text, no need to show it as artwork. Simply copy&paste the code and any plain text output into the question. This will increase response a lot.

Comment: Your code is in C++ not in C.

Comment: You pass to the thread a pointer to the local variable. By the time the thread gets around to accessing it, chances are high that variable is already destroyed. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race.

Comment: Why would you want to use pthreads directly rather than `std::thread` and friends?  Also, remember that you need synchronization for variables accessed from more than one thread. And then there's the lifetime issue that @Igor mentioned.

Comment: Thank you all very much =)
I am very glad that I understood why this is happening.
Perhaps this problem will be solved with 'pthread_join'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int rec = pthread_create(id_stream, NULL, PrintMessage, (void *)&call_mess)
```

This creates a new thread, passing to it a pointer to `call_mess`, as a parameter to `PrintMessage`.

This, the parent thread, ***immediately*** continues running, it returns from `pthread_create()` and reaches the end of the loop, at which point the `call_mess` object gets destroyed. `call_mess` exists only until the end of the `for` loop, at which point it gets destroyed before the `for` loop iterates again (or not).

You have ***absolutely no guarantees whatsoever*** that the new thread will start running, will read the pointer that it receives as a parameter, and will make a copy of it, before `call_mess` gets destroyed at the end of the loop in the parent thread. The only guarantee `pthread_create` gives you is that the new thread will start executing. Some time in some unspecified future, and it may not be even running yet after `pthread_create()` returns. But it will run. Some day. Some time. Eventually.

So what's obviously happening here is that this `call_mess` object is getting destroyed before each new thread reads it. That's it. Welcome to the world of multiple execution threads. This results in undefined behavior, and random garbage results that you see.

In order to do this correctly you will have to write more code, employing mutexes and condition variables, to make the parent thread wait until the new thread starts executing and fetches its parameters, and have the parent thread resume execution only after the child thread fetched out its parameters.